# Different width tire?

Tags: tires

My car has 225/50r17 tires. I have a set of four winter tires from my last car that are still good. They're 215/50r17. Given that they're fairly close in side, with the same radius, just 10mm thinner - can I save $700 on new tires and get these installed on the new car?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those tires should fit fine, when you get them fitted do ask the fitter to check they are still in good condition.

Winter tires degrade over time - especially in sunlight, so their performance is severely reduced after 2 years or so...

I, personally, change my winter tires so they only ever do 2 winter seasons ie November to April to keep the performance...

Answer (score -1):

you can install those tires, when this tires are fitted then ask the tire fitter to check the tires properly; that the tires are in good condition or not....

The winter tires degrade the of usage, the sunlight effect the tires which reduce the usage of the tires using it for 2 years........

so I advice you that install the tires of your old car into new one. these tires can work for you atleast  for 2 years...

Comment: This is literally a barely changed re-wording of Solar Mike's answer?